# Laravel artisan command doesn't finish properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have an artisan command that processes jobs in a table. reverseMatchSystemItem() method in turn processes all the products of a specific supplier context. For a specific supplier (which takes the longest time) the command is not getting finished. After every operation is done for all suppliers (I also tried it with just the one supplier), and after the inactive jobs are deleted, it keeps running (cursor blinking, with error log empty!) and interestingly CPU usage keeps increasing.

```
public function handle()
{
    $jobs = ReverseMatchProductJobs::all();
    try {
        foreach ($jobs as $job) {
            if ($job->object_type == 'product') {
                foreach (Supplier::all() as $supplier) {
                    $supplier->api()->reverseMatchSystemItem(Item::find($job->object_id));
                }
            } elseif ($job->object_type == 'size') {
                foreach (Supplier::all() as $supplier) {
                    $supplier->api()->reverseMatchSystemItemOption(ItemOption::find($job->object_id));
                }
            }
            $job->active = false;
            $job->save();
        }
        DB::table('reverse_match_product_jobs')->where('active', false)->delete();
        // die();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        var_dump($ex);
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the die() after the delete() operation, it gets finished properly but I am wondering if it kills the process in between. How can I debug this better to know what's wrong?

Edit: The same process runs perfectly with Tinker.

Comment: you can debug just about anything with xdebug

Comment: What should I try and debug here? All the expressions are executed and it just waits, if I try and dump values in the process they all return fine. And after all that it gets stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those questions that is going to be quite difficult to answer on Stackoverflow without tinkering with the query directly. However, your question is how to debug, so I will focus on that:

I would start with:

- Comment out the inner 2x foreach loops, but leave the `action` and `save` parts.
- Does that complete?
- If it does complete, you know something is wonky with those inner loops.
- If it does not complete, try comment out the outer loop, and checks if it completes
- And so forth

Outside of that, there is not a lot that can be done without more info